# QGIS Oracle-Spatial-GeoRaster-Plugin not working

Tags: oracle, plugins, geospatial, raster, qgis

I am having trouble with Oracle-Spatial-GeoRaster-Plugin in QGIS (running on Windows 7 Professional N 64bit). The connection to my database on an external Oracle-Server obviously works as it shows the containing rasters in the database. But as soon as I try to open a raster an error message comes up with the information that the connection could not be established. I should check the connection options and make sure the GDAL-Georaster-Plugin is installed.

I tried it with three independent standalone versions of QGIS (all 64bit):
- QGIS 2.14.3 running with GDAL 2.1.0
- QGIS 2.12.2 running with GDAL 1.11.3
- QGIS 2.10.1 running with GDAL 1.11.2

On my system I installed GDAL 2.1.0 with gdal-oracle-oci-driver (with OSGeo4W) and I know I could load Oracle rasters in QGIS with an earlier version of QGIS. When I updated the GDAL-version on my system it was not working any more.

My Questions:
- Is there another plugin apart from the "oracle-spatial-georaster"-plugin like written in the error message ("GDAL-georaster)? I don't find it.
- With which GDAL-Version is QGIS running? I thought QGIS installs its own GDAL-version and doesn't use the system-GDAL, but apparently its not working any more since I installed the recent GDAL-version on my system.
- Is there any other solution or has anybody hints of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: do you have Enterprise Edition? do you have a license for the GeoRaster plugin? as far as i know it's a payable feature

Comment: Yes. Oracle 12c Enterprise Edition. I could load the GeoRaster-plugin without license and it already worked earlier...